# Importing microblaze to sysgen

Tags: fpga

I designed some logic in matlab/simulink and now I want to import microblaze there, which will handle a communication via serial port and it will also sets some parameteres inside logic through from register blocks. I created the microblaze at XPS and then export through EDK processor block and HDL netlisting to matlab/simulink. I also add shared memories at edk processor block. Everythings works fine until i tried to create a hw-cosim block. Then i got an error:

Begin generation
Checking model status
Checking simulation times
Performing compilation and generation

*** ERROR ***

Errors occurred during netlist generation.
Reference to non-existent field 'memmap_info'.

Any help will be highly appreciated. :)

My configuration:
Matlab 2011a
Windows 7
Ise 13.4 Design edition

Thanks,
Ondrej

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check:

- Upgrade your ISE version.
- Verify that the generated instances have the proper names after create them.